# I am completely new to Python and Pandas and was wondering about how to output correctly

Tags: python, pandas

Please excuse my mistakes I am really new to Python and Pandas.

Would this code output correctly? There's is a certain format that I wanted it to be in output.

```
    if series == df.index
            print(f"Range: {df.iloc[0]} - {df.iloc[-1]}") 
    else if series == "gender"
    #need to do part where it prints the missing part
    else if series == "height"
            print(f"Range: {df.iloc[0]} - {df.iloc[-1]}")
            mean = df['height'].mean()
            print(f"Mean: {mean}")
            standard = df['height'].std()
            print(f"Standard deviation: {standard}")
            medium = df['height'].median()
            print(f"Median: {medium}")
    else if series == "waist"
            print(f"Range: {df.iloc[0]} - {df.iloc[-1]")
            mean2 = df['waist'].mean()
            print(f"Mean: {mean2}")
            standard2 = df['waist'].std()
            print(f"Standard deviation: {standard2}")
            medium2 = df['waist'].median()
            print(f"Median: {medium2}")
    else if series == "salary" 
     """need to do part for the missing part"""
    else if series == "dob"
            print(f"Range: {df.iloc[0]} - {df.iloc[-1]}")
    else if series == "death"
            print(f"Range: {df.iloc[0]} - {df.iloc[-1]}")
```

Comment: You are missing some quotes in your code that make it impossible for anyone else to run. Please fix this.

Comment: If we don't know what format you want, or what format you're getting, how can we possibly answer your question?

Comment: Also, what is the format you want? What happens when you run your code? Please [edit] your question to explain more.

Comment: welcome to SO. please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And `else if` is not a Python statement.  It has to be `elif`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.